# Routing URL from moving from localhost to servers with HTML5 path not correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am use to working with MVC and previously Web Forms  of asp.net so with those View Engines to Server ...  I never had to worry about when I worked with visual studio on local computer to **publishing the website to servers.**

However, the way I started building websites is with **HTML5 calling up Web Api**

Basically so that I can easily work locally and promote the code i end up doing this "hack"  is there a better way?

As you see **if not** detecting **localhost** i have it **add** in  **DOCCCO**

Its a **Web Api project in which I use plan HTML files with jquery ajax calls** ..

**locally it renders to   localhost:455434/whatever.html**
**server then  is     servername/DOCCCO/whatever.html**

Thus the SERVERNAME is = localhost:port   , but the project name is getting injected / appended as it has to on the server as there are many projects.

**So what are my options with more barebones HTML5 ?**
1. fix localhost:port  to always have  localhost:port/DOCCCO   , how?
2. fix web api Webapiconfig.cs  or routeconfig.cs  ???

```
<script>
            if (document.location.hostname === "localhost") {
                document.write('<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"><\/script>');
                document.write('<script src="/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"><\/script>');

                document.write('<script src="/Scripts/app.js"/><\/script>');
                document.write('<script src="/Scripts/flexdropdown.js"/><\/script>');

            }
            else {
                document.write('<script src="/DOCCCO/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"><\/script>');
                document.write('<script src="/DOCCCO/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"><\/script>');

                document.write('<script src="/DOCCCO/Scripts/app.js"><\/script>');
                document.write('<script src="/DOCCCO/Scripts/flexdropdown.js"/><\/script>');

            }
        </script>
```

Comment: If you use a build tool or something to compile all of your scripts you won't need to worry about injecting a ton of scripts.

Comment: true,  so what exactly would you propose with a web api 2 project with html files and css and javascript files?    msbuild  ?   Any links to examples and options would be appreciated   thx

Comment: Well, even bundling could do this for you as well.

Comment: I think automatic bundling and minification are features of MVC. You could create an MVC project even if it is just serving a SPA (single-page application) and make use of these features. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use relative rather than absolute URLs, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls).

That means defining the URLs without the leading slash, e.g. "Scripts/app.js" instead of "/Scripts/app.js"